# Python 3 - graphicalTriangle - string formatting/functions

Tags: python, python-3.x

was wondering if anyone can point out my error in the last string (area,perimeter) - any assistance would be greatly appreciated. )

```
message = Text(Point(5, 0.5),"The perimeter is: {0:0.2f}".format(perimeter))
message.draw(win)
message2 = Text(Point(5, 1),"The area is: {0:0.2f}".format(a))
message2.draw(win)
```

#### Full Code #####

```
# Program: triangle.py
import math
from graphics import *

def square(x):
    return x * x

def distance(p1, p2):
    dist = math.sqrt(square(p2.getX() - p1.getX()) + square(p2.getY() - p1.getY()))
    return dist

def perimeter():
    # Calculate the perimeter of the triangle
    perimeter = distance(p1,p2) + distance(p2,p3) + distance(p3,p1)
    return perimeter

def area():
    # Calculate the area of the triangle
    base = (distance(p3, p1) * (1 / 2))
    height = ((base) ** 2) - (distance(p1, p2) ** 2)
    h = math.sqrt(square(height))
    a = ((1/2) * (base) * h)
    return a

def main():
    win = GraphWin("Draw a Triangle")
    win.setCoords(0.0, 0.0, 10.0, 10.0)
    message = Text(Point(5, 0.5), "Click on three points")
    message.draw(win)

    # Get and draw three vertices of triangle
    p1 = win.getMouse()
    p1.draw(win)
    p2 = win.getMouse()
    p2.draw(win)
    p3 = win.getMouse()
    p3.draw(win)

    # Use Polygon object to draw the triangle
    triangle = Polygon(p1,p2,p3)
    triangle.setFill("black")
    triangle.setOutline("blue")
    triangle.draw(win)


    message = Text(Point(5, 0.5),"The perimeter is: {0:0.2f}".format(perimeter))
    message.draw(win)
    message2 = Text(Point(5, 1),"The area is: {0:0.2f}".format(a))
    message2.draw(win)

    # Wait for another click to exit
    win.getMouse()
    win.close()

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems.

The immediate problem is that you are trying to format the function "perimeter" and undefined variable "a".  The "f" format specifier requires a float, so it's probably complaining about that.

The other big problem is that you are not calling the perimeter() and area() functions.

The next problem, which may not have shown up yet, because the functions aren't being called, is that the perimeter and area functions are using variables that are local to the main function.

You need to modify perimeter() and area() to take p1, p2, and p3 as parameters, similar to how distance() takes p1 and p2 as parameters.  Then you need to update the code and the calls to format() so that the perimeter and area functions are actually called.  It might look like this:

```
p = perimeter(p1,p2,p3)
a = area(p1,p2,p3)
message = Text(Point(5, 0.5),"The perimeter is: {0:0.2f}".format(p))
message.draw(win)
message2 = Text(Point(5, 1),"The area is: {0:0.2f}".format(a))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you're not getting the correct results for the area calculation. There are two issues I see.

First, you're not calling your `perimeter` and `area` functions. You need to call them, and probably pass the collection of points in as parameters. (While I was writing this, Jeremiah answered this part too, quite clearly.)

The second issue is that I believe your calculation for the area of the triangle is wrong. You're trying to apply the formula `area = base * height / 2` but you don't have the base or height at the start and you're not calculating them correctly.

While it is possible to fix your base and height computations, instead I suggest is using a different (but mathematically equivalent) formula which better matches the data you have. Here's one way to do that, using the formula I found [here](http://www.mathopenref.com/coordtrianglearea.html):

```
def area(p0, p1, p2):                      # This code assumes points are tuples
    return abs((p0[0]*(p1[1]-p2[1]) +      # but the formula can work with any
                p1[0]*(p2[1]-p0[1]) +      # sort of point, just replace the
                p2[0]*(p0[1]-p1[1])) / 2)  # indexing with accessor calls.
```

Another option, since you're also calculating the perimeter, is to use [Heron's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula). To do this efficiently you'll want to find both the perimeter and area in the same function, so you can compute the lengths of the sides only once:

```
def perimeter_and_area(p0, p1, p2):
    a = distance(p0, p1)
    b = distance(p1, p2)
    c = distance(p2, p0)

    perimeter = a+b+c

    s = perimeter / 2   # semiperimeter
    area = math.sqrt(s * (s-a) * (s-b) * (s-c))

    return perimeter, area
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the assistance Jeremiah:

### Working Code for Assignment

```
import math

from graphics import *

def square(x):
    return x * x

def distance(p1, p2):
    # calculate distance between two points
    dist = math.sqrt(square(p2.getX() - p1.getX()) + square(p2.getY() - p1.getY()))
    return dist

def perimeter(tri):
    # Calculate the perimeter of the triangle
    points = tri.getPoints()
    p1 = points[0]
    p2 = points[1]
    p3 = points[2]
    perim = distance(p1,p2) + distance(p2,p3) + distance(p3,p1)
    return perim 

 def area(tri):
    # Calculate the area of the triangle
    points = tri.getPoints()
    p1 = points[0]
    p2 = points[1]
    p3 = points[2]
    base = (distance(p3, p1) * (1 / 2))
    height = ((base) ** 2) - (distance(p1, p2) ** 2)
    h = math.sqrt(square(height))
    a = (1/2) * ((base) * (h))
    return a


def main():
    # Setup graphWin
    win = GraphWin("Draw a Triangle")
    win.setCoords(0.0, 0.0, 10.0, 10.0)
    message = Text(Point(5, 0.5), "Click on three points")
    message.draw(win)

    # Get and draw three vertices of triangle
    p1 = win.getMouse()
    p1.draw(win)
    p2 = win.getMouse()
    p2.draw(win)
    p3 = win.getMouse()
    p3.draw(win)

    # Use Polygon object to draw the triangle
    triangle = Polygon(p1,p2,p3)
    triangle.setFill("black")
    triangle.setOutline("blue")
    triangle.draw(win)
    p = perimeter(triangle)
    a = area(triangle)

    # write text to graphWin
    message2 = Text(Point(5, 1),"The perimeter is: {0:0.2f}".format(p))
    message2.draw(win)
    message3 = Text(Point(5, 2),"The area is: {0:0.2f}".format(a))
    message3.draw(win)
    message.setText("Click again to close")

    # Wait for another click to exit
    win.getMouse()
    win.close()

main()
```

Comment: after reading blckkngt's post (much appreciated) im unsure about the accuracy of my area function. will repost code once i work that formula in. i think i pretty much did herons unknowingly